# C++ Expected type-specifier before 'XY' - In member function virtual void

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I work on my project (game in C++) and I found this error.

"Expected type-specifier before 'Clovek'
In member function virtual void"

This error is show for all - Clovek, PlatoveBrneni, ObourucniMec, BronzovyPrsten, LektvarCloveci.

For this project I use design pattern - builder.

Thanks for all replies!

### Here are codes:

CloverBuilder.h

```
#ifndef CLOVEK_BUILDER_H
#define CLOVEK_BUILDER_H

#include <iostream>
#include "HrdinaBuilder.h"
#include "Rasa.h"
#include "Brneni.h"
#include "Zbran.h"
#include "Prsten.h"
#include "Lektvar.h"

using namespace std;

namespace LordOfDragonV2 {
    class ClovekBuilder : LordOfDragonV2::HrdinaBuilder {


    public:
        void buildRasa(string nazevRasy, int silaRasy, int odolnostRasy, int inteligenceRasy, int pocetZivotaRasy, string popisRasy);

        void buildBrneni(string nazevBrneni, int bonusOdolnosti, int bonusZivota);

        void buildZbran(string nazevZbrane, int bonusSily, int bonusZivota);

        void buildPrsten(string nazevPrstenu, int bonusInteligence, int bonusZivota);

        void buildLektvar(string nazevLektvaru, int bonusSily, int bonusOdolnosti, int bonusInteligence, int bonusZivota);
    };
}

#endif //CLOVEK_BUILDER_H
```

---

ClovekBuilder.cpp

```
#include "ClovekBuilder.h"

void LordOfDragonV2::ClovekBuilder::buildRasa(string nazevRasy, int silaRasy, int odolnostRasy, int inteligenceRasy, int pocetZivotaRasy, string popisRasy) {
    m_hrdina->setRasa( new Clovek(nazevRasy, silaRasy, odolnostRasy, inteligenceRasy, pocetZivotaRasy, popisRasy) );
}

void LordOfDragonV2::ClovekBuilder::buildBrneni(string nazevBrneni, int bonusOdolnosti, int bonusZivota) {
    m_hrdina->setBrneni(new PlatoveBrneni(nazevBrneni, bonusOdolnosti, bonusZivota));
}

void LordOfDragonV2::ClovekBuilder::buildZbran(string nazevZbrane, int bonusSily, int bonusZivota) {
    m_hrdina->setZbran(new ObourucniMec(nazevZbrane, bonusSily, bonusZivota));
}

void LordOfDragonV2::ClovekBuilder::buildPrsten(string nazevPrstenu, int bonusInteligence, int bonusZivota) {
    m_hrdina->setPrsten(new BronzovyPrsten(nazevPrstenu, bonusInteligence, bonusZivota));
}

void LordOfDragonV2::ClovekBuilder::buildLektvar(string nazevLektvaru, int bonusSily, int bonusOdolnosti, int bonusInteligence, int bonusZivota) {
    m_hrdina->pridejLektvar(new LektvarCloveci(nazevLektvaru, bonusSily, bonusOdolnosti, bonusInteligence, bonusZivota));
}
```

Comment: Your compiler should tell you what line is giving the error. Can you find out and show us the code around that line?

Comment: The bit after "In member function virtual void" is quite relevant.

Answer (score 0):

You did not show where **Clovek** is declared. It is obvious that the compiler also does not see the corresponding declaration (and definition) of **Clovek**

You should include the header where this type is declared or/and defined.

For excample in this function you are trying to create an object of type **Clovek** using operator new:

```
void LordOfDragonV2::ClovekBuilder::buildRasa(string nazevRasy, int silaRasy, int odolnostRasy, int inteligenceRasy, int pocetZivotaRasy, string popisRasy) {
    m_hrdina->setRasa( new Clovek(nazevRasy, silaRasy, odolnostRasy, inteligenceRasy, pocetZivotaRasy, popisRasy) );
```

}

Or maybe you need to use a qualified name for example **LordOfDragonV2::Clovek** instead of **Clovek**